# Raster TIFF file does not project onto QGIS basemap correctly

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, georeferencing

Forgive me if this is a simple fix, I am new to QGIS 3.8. I have a .tif file that when opened into QGIS is projected on the (0,0) lat/long coordinate of the base map and is very small. I have confirmed the CRS for both is the same. My hunch is the lat and long on the .tif file may not match or is inconsistent with the base map. I tried to change the Metadata>Extent to match that of the base map with no luck. I have attached the .tif file below. Does anyone have any thoughts on how to get this data to project onto the base map correctly? The data is located over the Antarctic Peninsula. The .tif range is between Latitude(-60, -75) and Longitude(285,310)

https://www.dropbox.com/s/b6ri8c4inu3lzlv/2016_foehn_melt.tif?dl=0

Comment: Most likely the file is not (correctly) georeferenced, which you can do quite easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The likely scenario is that you require a [world file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_file) for the tif data.
This is an ascii text file with the same filename as the source `tif` but with a `tfw` extension, and contains the georeferencing for the data.  i.e. you will have:

- rastername.tif, and
- rastername.tfw

If you know the raster georeference details you can create this yourself.  There are 6 lines in the world file - these will define:

1. x pixel size
2. y rotation
3. x rotation
4. y pixel size
5. x coordinate center upper left pixel
6. y coordinate center upper left pixel

Further details are given by ESRI: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/raster-and-images/world-files-for-raster-datasets.htm